# Create a new repo and push all the code to created repo using octokit.rb - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, git-commit, octokit

[Octokit.rb](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb) is a `Ruby` toolkit for the `GitHub API`. I want to use it to create a new repo and then push my code to that repo. I am able to authenticate user but not able to create a repo. Can someone point me to the right direction, or if anyone knows any better `Github` api client please tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it myself, it's not present in the docs on github. You will find it here [Ruby Docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/pengwynn/octokit/Octokit/Client/Repositories#create_repository-instance_method)
And you will have to add origin like this to push to github

```
git remote add origin https://#{user_username}:#{user_access_token}@github.com/#{user_username}/#{project_name}.git"
```